# Suffix numbering

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to renumber records (grouped by family) in my table with a suffix sequential number but skipping the first record in the family. I am using SQL mgmt studio 2008.

```
ID = record number
FamilyID = group identifier

Current Numbering

ID           FamilyID   Existing_Num
SM00000002  UIS00000693 UIS00000694
SM00000003  UIS00000693 UIS00000694
SM00000004  UIS00000693 UIS00000694
SM00000006  UIS00000882 UIS00000883
SM00000007  UIS00000882 UIS00000883
SM00000008  UIS00000882 UIS00000883
SM00000010  UIS00001057 UIS00001058
SM00000011  UIS00001057 UIS00001058
SM00000012  UIS00001057 UIS00001058
SM00000014  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000015  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000016  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000017  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000018  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000019  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000020  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000021  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
```

Need to suffix current numbering so that it will display the following:

```
ID              FamilyID    New_Num
SM00000002  UIS00000693 UIS00000694
SM00000003  UIS00000693 UIS00000694_001
SM00000004  UIS00000693 UIS00000694_002
SM00000006  UIS00000882 UIS00000883
SM00000007  UIS00000882 UIS00000883_001
SM00000008  UIS00000882 UIS00000883_002
SM00000010  UIS00001057 UIS00001058
SM00000011  UIS00001057 UIS00001058_001
SM00000012  UIS00001057 UIS00001058_002
SM00000014  UIS00001193 UIS00001194
SM00000015  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_001
SM00000016  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_002
SM00000017  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_003
SM00000018  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_004
SM00000019  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_005
SM00000020  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_006
SM00000021  UIS00001193 UIS00001194_007
```

Here's the existing select query i have so far that results in my existing table:

```
select ID, FamilyID, 'UIS' + RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SUBSTRING([MsgSort1],25,8) + 1)),8) AS Existing_num
from table_name
```

Comment: That's very interesting but do you have any problems with that or a question?

Comment: Currently, I don't know of a way to generate a select or an update statement that would give me the numbers I reported in my result with the suffix numbers in the New_Num column

Comment: Is your server also 2008 or 2008R2?

Comment: Server 2008 R2 - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query. I could not test this. But the idea is that, you can use the Row_Number function to get the serial number for repeating rows. After that you can append the serial number to the existing number column.

```
;WITH table_cte(ID, FamilyID,Existing_num, seqNo)
AS
(
select ID, FamilyID, 
'UIS' + RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SUBSTRING([MsgSort1],25,8) + 1)),8) AS Existing_num,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ('UIS' + RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SUBSTRING([MsgSort1],25,8) + 1)),8))) AS SeqNo
)
select ID, FamilyID, Existing_num, 
CASE WHEN seqNo = 1 THEN Existing_num
ELSE Existing_num + '_' + Right('000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, seqNo-1), 3)
END AS New_Num   
from table_name;
```

Comment: In the else branch it should be seqNo-1 insteand of seqNo+1. As i understand OP the index is more or less zero based

Comment: What should i replace "table_cte" with, not sure if that corresponds to my own table. Sorry if this question sounds stupid

Comment: In Addition, I tested the query and receive the following error:
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

Comment: I was able to get the query working but unfortunately the results does not re-start the suffix numbering whenever a new familyID comes up. See below.

ID FamilyID Existing_num New_Num
SM00000002 UIS00000693 UIS00000694 UIS00000694
SM00000003 UIS00000693 UIS00000694 UIS00000694_001
SM00000004 UIS00000693 UIS00000694 UIS00000694_002
SM00000006 UIS00000882 UIS00000883 UIS00000883_003
SM00000007 UIS00000882 UIS00000883 UIS00000883_004
SM00000008 UIS00000882 UIS00000883 UIS00000883_005
SM00000010 UIS00001057 UIS00001058 UIS00001058_006
SM00000011 UIS00001057 UIS00001058 UIS00001058_007

Comment: @KiranHegde: Posted a working version of your idea and gave you an upvote.  It's hard without being to test your code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working idea of Kiran Hegde's idea.  I wouldn't post as a separate answer, but there seemed to be a lot more going on in the solution than necessary, and all the comments seemed to point towards errors in it.  So, I decided to post separately.  Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a144c/9

```
WITH cteNumbered
AS
(
  SELECT    ID,
            FamilyID,
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FamilyID ORDER BY ID)) - 1 AS Suffix
  FROM      Table1
)

SELECT    ID,
          FamilyID,
          CASE 
            WHEN Suffix <> 0 THEN FamilyID + '_' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(Suffix AS VARCHAR(10)), 3)
            ELSE FamilyID
          END AS New_Num
FROM      cteNumbered
ORDER BY  ID,
          Suffix;
```